# Computer goes to sleep immediately after wake up login on Juno

Tags: release-juno

I upgraded recently to Juno and have run into an issue. When I put my desktop to sleep it all goes fine but when I go and wake it up and type my password the computer screen goes black and the computer goes back again to sleep. I have to wake it up a second time to make it work.

How could I fix this issue? It never happened to me in Freya.

Thanks!